# Css side navigation transition

Tags: html, css

I have a side navigation bar that extends on a button click.

When I open the side navigation bar if the text is too long it displays first in 2 lines, then when we reach the full width of the side navigation it goes to 1 line.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
 
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.sidenav-item {
 display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="sidenav-item">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/35/35"/>
    <a href="#">Toto user creation</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

*On the exemple above, when the nav bar extends "Toto user creation" first display on 3 lines then the final display is on 2 lines. I want to display it directly on 2 lines*

I tried **transition:none** for the text only but it's not working.

Any ideas to make the text appears on X lines directly depending on the width of the text?

Comment: we did not get your exact problem and what you want to do? please explain

Comment: Could you post some of the code you have tried so we can see what you have and what the problem is?

Comment: @PrakashKarena I tried to edit the question so my display "issue" might be clearer

Comment: @binjamin the only code I could think of is css : transition:none on the text but it's not working as expected and I think the display would be worst. since the full text would be shown before the nav bar fully extended

Comment: Is it really a problem? I wouldn't have noticed if you didn't mention it. **Edit:** If the transition is .25 I don't think it's noticeable.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question, and never a link to any third party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `.sidenav-item` `min-width: 250px;` and the text won't move on fold

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
 
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.sidenav-item {
 display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="sidenav-item">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/35/35"/>
    <a href="#">Toto user creation</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the case the sidenav has a non extended width of 20px (with icons), then it extends with text. min-width:250px is not enough right, it would broke the set the non extended width to 250 ?

Answer (score 1):

use CSS animation

```js
function openNav() {  document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.add("sidenav-open");
}

function closeNav() {  document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.remove("sidenav-open");
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
  width:0;
}
.sidenav-open {
 width:250px;
}
.show-text { opacity:0; }
.sidenav-open .show-text {
 animation: mymove 0.5s linear 0.2s both;
}
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
 
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.sidenav-item {
 display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
   display:none;
  }
  to {opacity: 1;
   display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" >
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div  class="sidenav-item">
   <img class="show-text" src="https://picsum.photos/35/35"/>
    <a  class="show-text"href="#">Toto user creation</a>
  </div>
  <a class="show-text" href="#">Services</a>
  <a  class="show-text" href="#">Clients</a>
  <a  class="show-text" href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this solution? I think this answer will help you to fix the issue.

Here I have applied `white-space: nowrap;` for menu items in side navigation,so it won't be breaked to multiple lines when collapse the navigation.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidenav a img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.sidenav-item {
display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="sidenav-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/35/35"/>Toto user creation</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "auto";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

[Js Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/vLjw7heb/13/)